# Looking for the proper syntax to set setmaxlifecycle on my tabbed application

Tags: kotlin, tabs, lifecycle

I'm just a hack and a newbie...I've received a lot of good information on this site but can't seem to find the answer to setting the max life cycle of a fragment, such that when it is selected, the `onResume()` for that fragment is executed.

I've created a simple 3-tab application from the help of youTube videos and haven't figured out to properly set the lifecycle. I'm not sure how much information I should include, so i'll start with this:

```
val tabLayout: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout)
val viewPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
val viewPagerAdpater = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

viewPagerAdpater.addFragment(SummaryFragment(), "Summary")
viewPagerAdpater.addFragment(BoxFragment(), "Box")
viewPagerAdpater.addFragment(SettingsFragment(), "Settings")

viewPager.adapter = viewPagerAdpater
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
```

I've tried this, which crashes:

> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().setMaxLifecycle(viewPagerAdpater.getItem(1),Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)

There is also this code:

```
internal class ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    private val fragments: ArrayList<Fragment>
    private val titles: ArrayList<String>

    init{
        fragments = ArrayList<Fragment>()
        titles = ArrayList<String>()
    }
    
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragments[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return fragments.size
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String){
       fragments.add(fragment)
        titles.add(title)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(i: Int): CharSequence? {
        return titles[i]
    }
}
```

Thanks and let me know if more information is required...

Comment: What is the exception message when it crashes?

Comment: The emulator just says the app keeps stopping. If i comment out the setmaxlifecycle line, the program works fine.